# XC90 D5 Oil fill triggers Engine management code

Tags: engine, oil, xc90

Does anyone have any documentation/service letters regarding the XC90s engine management code that gets activated when you fill oil to the level? A Volvo garage told me there was too much oil, and it cost $100 for the diagnosis and to empty out some oil. Second time this happened. Not impressed. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. Understanding your frustration, I am sorry to say you have not given enough detail. What code? What year? How many miles? Did you do the oil change? How much oil was put in? This is the second time this has happened, in what time period? Please use the [edit] feature to add details to your post.

Comment: A quick Internet search found this...[Engine System Service Required Error Code 95](http://www.volvo-forums.com/t38683-engine-system-service-required-error-code-95.htm). The person describes the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

As found on the link posted by CharlieRB, this is a known problem on specific Volvo engines. The dipstick "max" line doesn't agree with the oil level sensor. Only fill engine oil to the 3/4 mark on the dipstick.